# React-chartjs options doesn't take effect

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I have my data and option for react-chartjs charts configured as

```
var lagData = [{
    options: {
      // Boolean - If we should show the scale at all


    showScale: true,
    // Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
    pointDot: true,
    showLines: false,
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
           boxWidth: 50,
           fontSize: 10,
           fontColor: '#bbb',
           padding: 5,

        }
    }
},
    data: {
        labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Current lag',
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 1,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                spanGaps: false,
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                scaleOverride: true, scaleStartValue: 0, scaleStepWidth: 1, scaleSteps: 30,
                data: [50, 35, 60, 67]
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

I am uing it in my code as

```
<Line data={lagData[0].data} options={lagData[0].options} width="600" height="300" />
```

This is how I have imported the library

```
import {Line, Bar} from 'react-chartjs';
import Chart from 'chartjs';
```

Surprisingly the data gets plotted onto the chart but the options don't affect the chart at all. I can't quite figure out the problem. Am I formatting it wrong or I am missing out something very silly.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

After changing `import Chart from 'chart.js';` to `import Chart from 'chartjs';`, Some of the direct configurations like `showScale, pointDot, showLines` and some of the datasets options are rendered but the `title and legends` are still not displaying.

Comment: @shubnam were you able to change things like `Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;`. These do not work for me either

Answer (score 0):

The react-chartjs does not support Chart.js V2.

Please refer the documentation of Chart.js v1.1.1. (https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/v1.1.1/docs)

If you want to use Chart.js V2, please try chartjs-v2 branch.

```
npm i react-chartjs@git://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs.git#chartjs-v2
```

For more information go to https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs/issues/134#issuecomment-233499768